# email notification in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, database-administration

I have a stored procedure which has 2 parameters `@LastUpdateDate` and `@CurrentDate`
I calculate the difference between these two days and store it in another variable called Sub, like this

```
declare @sub int
select @sub = (datediff(dd,@LastUpdate,@CurrentDate))
```

If the value of Sub is greater than 0, I want to send an email notification to few people that the cube has not been refreshed since last day.

Can any one tel me how I can achieve this ? I tried sqldbmail, but that option didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send email from SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server)

Comment: There are many many guides on using SQL Mail. Tell us specifically what you did and how it didn't work and we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about sqldbmail. The standard would be to use [sp_send_dbmail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

It requires some set up which is discussed in the accepted answer to [How to send email from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server) as Leo commented.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm a fan of [ab]using SQL Agent for this - assuming that this is a scheduled check and I'm only contacting SQL-admin-bods...

I would set up a job with a single T-SQL step with code along the lines of:

```
EXEC your_sproc 'etc', 'etc';

IF DateDiff(dd, @LastUpdate, @CurrentDate) > 0
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Cube not refreshed', 18, 1);
  END
;
```

Then I would set a notification email when the job fails

[image]