# How to continuously check a condition in sql server 2012 and trigger a mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I'm doing a project called personal manager using ASP.NET 4.5 using C# and SQL Server 2012. As an example I store the details of driving license including it's expiry date.

What I want to do is to check this expiry date and present date and find whether it matches. If it matches I want to send a mail to the person informing the same.

I read about triggers and stored procedure but don't know how to implement this.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the Internet. See also DoMyHomework.com

Comment: I suggest you do some research on SQL Agent - using this you can run a stored proc (or anything else) at a regular time. This is basically what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few option's to do it
Use sql agent to run each day 
and then send email,

how to send email from ms-sql
[How to send email from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server)

You can write some windows service to run query every day or hour and run query
like select * from license where expiredate < DateNow()
and AllReadySend=false

Then send email's from window service.

Comment: thanks janusz nowak for helping and i think you could support me in this regard in future. Thank you