# Julia | How to send Email through Julia code

Tags: email, analytics, julia, ijulia-notebook

Is there a way to send emails to an email id through julia code?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 4):

[SMTPClient](https://github.com/aviks/SMTPClient.jl) Package is useful for sending emails from within Julia code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which has a bit more overhead, is to use for example [ODBC.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDatabases/ODBC.jl) and [send an email via SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server)