# Why should I not use Microsoft Studio Manager to email?

Tags: sql-server, email

I was reading the post at [How to send email from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server) and was all excited because I need to do this as well, but then I read the below comment.

> "You shouldn't use SQL server as an app server. Setting up emails to alert you is one thing, but using it as an email distributor is something else. While you CAN do this, you may want to concider if you SHOULD do this. – Dan Andrews Apr 10 '14 at 13:52"

Why should you not send emails through SQL? I am sure there is a good reason but I can not find it on the internet. Not to ask an open ended question but what would be a good app server that sends automated emails?

Comment: What is the workload emails that you are expecting? I use it to send result sets to users on a daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly basis. So the workload is not huge.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, you want your SQL Server machine to be focused on one thing, that being running SQL Server efficiently. SQL Server is great at being a relational database system. It has DBMail as a feature, but it's not designed to send loads of emails for your whole application. It's likely more efficient to send emails through something like SendGrid. There are probably tons of other suggestions.

Bottom line: let SQL Server do what it's good at, and don't take away resources by using it as an email system.