# How to send an email to outlook when a record is inserted in my Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I need to know if it is possible to create a trigger that would send an email to outlook when a record is inserted into a database?

E.g When record A is inserted, the trigger will run and send an email to the admin to inform them of a change.

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server

Comment: look at using Database mail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh245116.aspx

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using Creating Alerts under SQL Server Agent from ssms and prior this you need to configure the Database Mail Under Management in ssms.