# How to send emails by any format using different SQL Select statements?

Tags: sql-server, email, select-query

I have few SQL Scripts (4 select statements & each 2 from 2 different databases).

I need to add them and set all in single e-mail sending in .csv or HTML format. Is there any option in SSMS or do I have any options? I tried with UNION ALL and did lot google search but not much info helps me.

Comment: Are the databases accessible via the same connection?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yes and both DB's in same instance.

Comment: Did the `Union All` work? Have you tried `BCP` to create the `.csv` file?

Comment: So which part exactly do you need help with?  Retrieving the data from the database(s) or displaying it somewhere?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter for sending an email using SQL Scripts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter mostly not, I al ready checked that one. I need to add multiple selects from 2 different databases in to one email.

Comment: So what is preventing you? There is nothing magical about queries pulling data from multiple databases. Just write your query that pulls addresses or whatever and the technique for sending them is absolutely no different at all.